# NoReverseMatch at /article/add/

Tags: django, django-urls

I've been building my blog in Django and been able to add a list view and an article detail view but my add view isn't working.

I have tried every suggestion I saw online. None of them work for me.

Here is my add post HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 2rem; margin-bottom: 2rem;">
        x
        <h1>Add Blog Post</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'article-detail' post.slug %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Post
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
  
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ArticleListView, AddPostView, ArticleDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('article/add/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add-post'),
    path('article/<slug:slug>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
]
```

Here are my class based views

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.


class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 3


class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    context_object_name = 'post'


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
```

Comment: Please add the complete error trace

Comment: `form action="{% url 'article-detail' post.slug %}` -> `form action="{% url 'add-post' %}`

Answer (score 0):

What does `action="{% url 'article-detail' post.slug %}"` even mean? Firstly this is a `CreateView` so the post doesn't exist yet. Next why would you submit the form to the detail view? Change your form tag to forego the `action` attribute:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 2rem; margin-bottom: 2rem;">
        x
        <h1>Add Blog Post</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Post
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
  
{% endblock content %}
```

If you want to redirect after the creation of the object to the detail view you should either override `get_success_url` in your view or add a `get_absolute_url` method to your model.

To override `get_success_url`:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

To add a `get_absolute_url` method to your model:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    # your fields and other methods here
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Thatfixed it1